# Formatting a decimal within a toString method?

Tags: java, rounding

I am working on a project that implements base costs of shipping fees and whatnot and I need to be able to format the toString so that it displays the cost with 2 decimal places. I already did some research on rounding and implemented the BigDecimal rounding method:

```
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}

private double baseCost() {

    double cost = (weightInOunces * costPerOunceInDollars);
    cost = round(cost, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return cost;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "From: " + sender + "\n" + "To: " + recipient + "\n"
            + carrier + ": " + weightInOunces + "oz" + ", "
            + baseCost();
}
```

However, when it goes to print the value $11.50, it comes out at $11.5. I know how to format a decimal in a System.out.format() style, but I'm not sure how that could be applied to a toString. How could I format this so that all decimals are displayed to two values? I'm also wondering if I should even use BigDecimal, seeing as that has not been introduced in the class yet.  Are there any other easy to implement rounding methods that will also format the display of the double value? Or should I just format the decimal within the toString method?

Comment: IMHO only override `toString` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Slightly off topic but you should be using `BigDecimal` for money throughout, not doubles, not double, and that `round()` technique doesn't actually work, as doubles don't have decimal places, they have binary places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply `DecimalFormat` in `toString`. Regarding the appropriateness of `BigDecimal`, if you are dealing with money, which you are, where precision is required, use BigDecimal.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

   DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

   return "From: " + sender + ... + format.format(baseCost());
}
```

If you return `BigDecimal` instead of `double` from your `round` method, the floating precision will not be lost.

Comment: Okay, I implemented the DecimalFormat just like you said in the toString and it works great. However, I'm having to add that in to each of my sub classes to get the same result with values appended to the toString from the super class. How exactly do I format DecimalFormat within the BigDecimal method? When I tried to do that it gave an error that it was given a String when a double was required.

Comment: Can't say without seeing the code that's giving the problem. If `baseCost` returned a `BigDecimal` you could simple use `setScale`. see update.

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work. I just implemented the `BigDecimal` function in my `Package` class (superclass), and then just called the super method in each of my two subclasses. I did, however, have to create a `DecimalFormat` instance in my `toString` for each subclass though. I was looking for something to smooth that out, but for the sake of this project, it just needs to function. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat` to print the `double` as a `String` with two decimal places.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    return "From: " + sender + "\n" + "To: " + recipient + "\n"
            + carrier + ": " + weightInOunces + "oz" + ", "
            + df.format(baseCost());
}
```